# typeError while adding items to list through a function

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror

so currently im working on a function where you add countries you visit, times visited and cities visited to a list however  whenever i add the arguments to the list through the function i get a type error

here is my code
ps: im still learning and the requirements are that i have to add the items through a function

code

```
travel_log = [
{
  "country": "France",
  "visits": 12,
  "cities": ["Paris", "Lille", "Dijon"]
},
{
  "country": "Germany",
  "visits": 5,
  "cities": ["Berlin", "Hamburg", "Stuttgart"]
},
]
# Do NOT change the code above
def add_new_country(country, times_visited, cities_visited):
    travel_log["country"] = country
    travel_log["times_visited"] = times_visited
    travel_log["Cities_visited"] = cities_visited
    

# Do not change the code below
add_new_country("Russia", 2, ["Moscow", "Saint Petersburg"])
print(travel_log)
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\(my name is here)\2.py", line 21, in <module>
    add_new_country("Russia", 2, ["Moscow", "Saint Petersburg"])
  File "C:\Users\(also my name)\2.py", line 15, in add_new_country
    travel_log["country"] = country
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append a dict to list:

```
def add_new_country(country, times_visited, cities_visited):
     travel_log.append({'country': country, 'visits': times_visited, 'cities': cities_visited})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a list and not a dict , and the country should be the key

Instead of:

```
travel_log = [
{
  "country": "France",
  "visits": 12,
  "cities": ["Paris", "Lille", "Dijon"]
},
{
  "country": "Germany",
  "visits": 5,
  "cities": ["Berlin", "Hamburg", "Stuttgart"]
},
]
```

you should have:

```
travel_log ={"France":{  "visits": 12,  "cities": ["Paris", "Lille", "Dijon"]},
{"Germany","visits": 5,  "cities": ["Berlin", "Hamburg", "Stuttgart"]}}
```

And always add a check if key exist in dict , otherwise you will override the old data instead of updating the values